# Zeppelin fails to load on docker: logErrors docker zeppelin

Tags: docker, apache-zeppelin

First issue I´m having is that I can not pull the base image without specifying the version tag, not a big deal... but I find it odd, after that

```
docker pull apache/zeppelin:0.8.2
```

After that I´m able to get the image, but one I try to run it as:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080  apache/zeppelin:0.8.2
```

or

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 --rm --name zeppelin apache/zeppelin:0.8.2
```

The browser just don´t show any result at the corresponding port: localhost:8080/

In the terminal I get a series of warnings an the following error:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors logErrors docker zeppelin
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zeppelin Docker documentation is missing. You can find some recent fixes in their repo, e.g. env variable `ZEPPELIN_ADDR=0.0.0.0`:

```
docker run --rm -ti \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  -e ZEPPELIN_ADDR=0.0.0.0 \
  --name zeppelin \
  apache/zeppelin:0.8.2
```

Comment: Awesome! how come the basic example fails…