# Setup zeppelin in docker without using built-in image

Tags: docker, apache-zeppelin

I need to install zeppelin in docker without using the build-in image, because of its huge size (in gb).  I want to install zeppelin from the binary file, for example zeppelin-0.8.2-bin-netinst.tgz (Only spark interpreter ~ 318 mb)

My Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8
RUN wget -O /tmp/zeppelin-0.8.2-bin-netinst.tgz https://mirror.downloadvn.com/apache/zeppelin/zeppelin-0.8.2/zeppelin-0.8.2-bin-netinst.tgz
RUN tar -xvzf /tmp/zeppelin-0.8.2-bin-netinst.tgz -C /opt && rm /tmp/zeppelin-0.8.2-bin-netinst.tgz
EXPOSE 8080
```

I build the docker images & run container

```
docker build -t test:1.0 .
docker run -p 8080:8080 -it test:1.0 /bin/bash
```

And start zeppelin manually

```
/opt/zeppelin-0.8.2-bin-netinst/bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh start
```

I received the result

```
Zeppelin start                                             [  OK  ]
```

But when I access zeppelin from the browser at http://localhost:8080/, I received:

```
This page isn’t working
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

I tried run the command  **bin/zeppelin.sh** but nothing appeared.
Where did I go wrong?

I checked my container with **docker ps** command and the result sas:

```
5d37f4a18a53        test:1.0            "/bin/bash"         27 minutes ago      Up 27 minutes       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   brave_bardeen
```

If I telnet from the docker host: **telnet localhost 8080** and it works. Why Can't I access zeppelin from the browser?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: When i install on local same the way i present above. It's work

Comment: i would potentially start with the official docker base image first and remove the element that you don't want. https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/zeppelin/dockerfile 
 but would have though you needed spark or python or R.

Comment: @shaine Thank for your reply. But built-in zeppelin docker image use FROM ubuntu:16.04. Devops team recommended for me,don't use it when i apply our company CICD system. Don't FROM ubuntu. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some useful post:
[Zeppelin fails to load on docker: logErrors docker zeppelin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59254456/zeppelin-fails-to-load-on-docker-logerrors-docker-zeppelin)

We need to set ZEPPELIN_ADDR=0.0.0.0, now i can access zeppelin from browser localhost

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e ZEPPELIN_ADDR=0.0.0.0 -it test:1.0 /bin/bash
```